# not able to install freeipa-server on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04, freeipa

I am trying to install freeipa-server on ubuntu but not getting it installed as i am getting below error:

```
sudo apt-get install freeipa-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package freeipa-server
```

I have tried it on ubuntu 14.04 and also on ubuntu 16.04 but no luck. freeipa-client gets installed fine but not freeipa-server. Any idea how can i get this resolved?

Many Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: As an alternative I would suggest docker edition of freeipa server.  https://www.freeipa.org/page/Docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package seems to be available for [16.04 only](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&keywords=freeipa). It's in *universe*, so please make sure you have it marked under "Software & Updates" and run `sudo apt update`.

To add the repository you can also edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` or invoke:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @wrwrwr, i am using AWS AMI image for ubuntu 16.04   - in this case how can i mark it under "Software & Updates"?

Comment: Excellent!! it works like charm.. Thank you so much.